# ERROR/MemoryFile: MemoryFile.finalize() called while ashmem still open

Tags: android, imageview, uri

A simple test application: one ImageView, two Button and one function

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    String photoId = (v.getId() == R.id.button1)?"2472":"2434";
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, photoId);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageURI(uri);
}
```

Several times I click buttons - photos are loaded correctly. But LogCat says (several lines): ERROR/MemoryFile: MemoryFile.finalize() called while ashmem still open.

Hmm...
Is it problem? How to use setImageURI?

Answer (score 2):

Now I use the following:

```
final java.io.InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri); 
final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
input.close();

imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

I'm not sure that it's better, but on it the LogCat is silent.